# OpenGL fail to load raw picture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am trying to execute a code that uses a raw picture as a texture. The problem is the picture wont load. Where do I need to put the picture so the program can locate it? It is currently in the project folder I am working on. I work in Codeblocks 12.11 (Win7, MinGW)

```
bool setup_textures()
{
    RGBIMG img;

    // Create The Textures' Id List
    glGenTextures(TEXTURES_NUM, g_texid);

    // Load The Image From A Disk File
    if (!load_rgb_image("glass_128x128.raw", 128, 128, &img)) return false;

    // Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texid[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, img.w, img.h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);

    // Create Linear Filtered Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texid[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, img.w, img.h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);

    // Create MipMapped Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texid[2]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, img.w, img.h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);

    // Finished With Our Image, Free The Allocated Data
    delete img.data;

    return true;
}
```

the problem is the line with the loading of glass_128x128.raw fails and returns false;

Comment: I'd guess you need your image *glass_128x128.raw* needs to be in the same directory as the `.exe` file.  Since there's nothing else in this routine that could return `false`, it's really likely that `load_rgb_image` is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to:

Project -> Properties -> Build targets -> [name of target] -> Execution working dir

and make sure that's set to the same directory as glass_128x128.raw. Chances are it's running from whatever directory your debug builds get put in, which isn't the same directory as your image is in.